# What are the limitations of buffer size of textBufferSetView in haskell using gtk?

Tags: haskell, gtk, gtk2hs

What is the buffer size? I can set a buffer to take in

> VC "Cons" [VC "Z" [],VC "Cons" [VC "S" [VC "Z" []],VC "Cons" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "Z"     []]],VC "Cons" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "Z" []]]],VC "Cons" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "Z" []]]]],VC "Cons" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "Z" []]]]]],VC "Cons" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "Z" []]]]]]],VC "Cons" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "Z" []]]]]]]],VC "Cons" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "Z" []]]]]]]]],VC "Nil" []]]]]]]]]]
>   VC "Cons" [VC "Z" [],VC "Cons" [VC "S" [VC "Z" []],VC "Cons" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "Z" []]],VC "Cons" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "Z" []]]],VC "Cons" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "Z" []]]]],VC "Cons" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "Z" []]]]]],VC "Cons" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "Z" []]]]]]],VC "Cons" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "Z" []]]]]]]],VC "Cons" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "S" [VC "Z" []]]]]]]]],VC "Nil" []]]]]]]]]]

It will not display and I am getting a rather large blue screen instead. This is very odd behaviour.

It will print `VC "True" []` happily though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add a minimal testcase showing something going weird? That string is pretty darn small by computer standards.